# Reload level button - restart to previous score - Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem on my restart button. 
My game is about catching things, when I catch a thing, the score is 1, if I catch a lot of things, score is like 10-11 (whatever), when I press the restart level button, the score is same, I mean 10-11, he is not restarting. 
I use PlayerPrefs, this is saving my score. And, If I press the next level button, the score is ok, but when I catch again things, in the new level, if I try to restart the level, the score is not the same like when the level start, score remain.

Is there a way to do, when I press the restart button and level starts again, the score to be like the first time?

Comment: only you control how the score is held, whatever you did to it, made it persistent or, you didnt reset it, We cant help without code. Please provide [mcve] and please also read [ask]

Comment: I have a lot of code, that's the problem, I don't know exactly what to give to see. I waited to someone tell me what code I can give to see my problem. I really don't understand how to resolve it, I thought that someone can give me some ideas.

Comment: well, you need to show enough code to replicate your problem but not enough we all go TL;DR

Comment: This question surely has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript] and does not warrant the [tag:visual-studio] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your PlayerPrefs.

Let's say your score is saved like so: `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score);`.
When you restart the level you should reset this "Score" aswell: `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);`

Comment: @Robbie make sure to click the checkmark on the answer if it's correct.

Comment: I didn't ask the question. only ppl who ask the question can click the check mark